# How to get the source of sent email message using the Gmail APIS

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

We are using Gmail APIS to send and webhooks to receive the emails. Is there any way to identify if the email is sent through APIS or if it's directly sent using Gmail interface.

We need this information to avoid the message echos in our API usage. We send the email using the API and we don't want to get that message in webhook. Incase we get it,